# Current time as Int

Tags: haskell

I'm looking for a way to represent the current time in Haskell like can do in Ruby:

```
Time.now.to_i
 => 1405771733
```

I tried this:

```
import Data.Time.Clock
currTime <- getCurrentTime

let timed = floor $ utctDayTime currTime :: Int -- 1
let timed = utctDayTime currTime :: Int -- 2
```

The first expression returned `43774` which didn't look like it was the right answer.

Comment: I'm not sure, but this looks like number of seconds since 0:00 UTC today.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17909770/get-time-as-int

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### tl;dr

Ruby's [`#to_i` method](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Time.html#method-i-to_i) returns the number of seconds since the UNIX Epoch (January 1, 1970 00:00 UTC). You can return the same number with the following function:

```
secondsFromEpoch :: UTCTime -> Int
secondsFromEpoch utc =
    let seconds = formatTime defaultTimeLocale "%s" utc
    in  read seconds
```

used as:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    currentTime <- getCurrentTime
    print $ secondsFromEpoch currentTime
```

[<kbd>Live demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/da9309c4b0aa8a03)

### How does this work

To understand this solution you can just read the [Date.Time.Format documentation](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/time-1.4.2/docs/Data-Time-Format.html), specifically at the `formatTime` function:

> %s
>
> number of whole seconds since the Unix epoch. For times before the Unix epoch, this is a negative number. Note that in %s.%q and %s%Q the decimals are positive, not negative. For example, 0.9 seconds before the Unix epoch is formatted as -1.1 with %s%Q.

Therefore:

```
formatTime defaultTimeLocale "%s" utc
```

will return the number of seconds in a string. Since it's an integer, we can use `read` and put it into an `Int`.

### Where was your mistake

An `UTCTime` is composed of:

- a `Day` (a day)
- a `DiffTime` (time from midnight)

The function `utctDayTime` has the following type:

```
utctDayTime :: UTCTime -> DiffTime
```

that is: it takes an `UTCTime` and returns the number of seconds from midnight. Therefore `utctDayTime` does not account for the day.

Comment: Converting to a String and then reading back doesn’t look like the best solution, and rather un-Haskellish.

Answer (score 4):

Use the [`Data.Time.Clock.POSIX`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/time-1.1.4/docs/Data-Time-Clock-POSIX.html) module in the [`time`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/time) package:

```
main :: IO ()
main = print =<< getPOSIXTime
```

This function returns an [`PosixTime`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/time-1.1.4/docs/Data-Time-Clock-POSIX.html#t:POSIXTime) (in the IO monad), which you can convert to an `Integer` with [`round`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:round) or [`floor`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:floor).